# How to change job to a programmer

Tags: new-job, career-development, job-change, career-switch

My question is pointed to anyone who changed his/her profession to programing. Of course learning programming is obvious. No doubt. I’m in the middle of online training. I wonder what might be my next option/ options. This is the question of possibilities (boot-camps, internships …), while still working in my old job. Final choice is up to me. Any experience based advice, or feasible ideas are those concepts I would appreciate.

Comment: how would you do a boot camp or internship while still working your current job?

Comment: Does your current job leave you enough free time to start programming as a hobby?  And does your current contract allow you to keep ownership of the copyright on code you write in your free time, so you can release what you produce under an open-source licence on GitHub or similar?

Comment: ... and does your current job involve you sitting in front of a computer doing repetitive tasks that you might be able (partly) to automate by writing a spreadsheet macro or similar?

Comment: If you can get a job in which you program part-time (e.g. to automate something your company is doing anyway) without it being your primary responsibility, that can be a good stepping stone and minimize risk. You should be aware that the path of spending a bunch of time and money on a "boot camp" does *not* work out for many, perhaps a majority, of the people who try it, unless you also have personal contacts who can then get you your first job -- which is where much of the real learning will take place. After that it's just a question of whether or not you were successful at that stage.

Comment: You have asked this question twice and gotten it closed twice. The problem with asking this question is that there are so many factors that go into a career switch including which country you are in, that this forum is not the correct place to ask a wide open question like you did. For example, you could start by finding problems at your current job that could be solved by doing some programming. See what it is like to try to solve real problems and maintain that solution for a year. Then, ask if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is a *craft*.  You need to learn this early.

What you are doing is education, and for programming, it is a required first step.

What you need to be employed is skill.  Skill is the ability to avoid mistakes and produce good products.  To develop skill, there is only one path: practice.

So to "get into" programming, learn and practice.  I see too many people who attempt to enter the field by learning only.  Consider it like Piano.  No matter how much you learn about music, without practice you will never play Piano well.

Once you have practiced enough that you can solve simple programming problems without using the Internet, you should do well in interviews.

I notice that all of your "next steps" involve learning, and none of them seem to involve much practice.  As skill is what is being asked for in an interview, I would state that none of these programs alone will help.

A good book on the subject is all that is generally needed for obtaining the information (spend a little time to discover the best book for your topic); but, two or more hours per day over a few weeks (or months, depending on the topic) is required to land the job.  Plan your money to support your skill building, as it will be more expensive (in time) than any class.

Comment: Almost anyone can learn the syntax of a programming language.  I would hope everyone in that group can learn the UI of Visual Studio and compile code.  A smaller subset will have the ability to diagnose what often is very vague compiler errors.  The smallest subset of that first group, who learned a syntax of a specific programming language, will be able to build something from scratch.  The entire point of this statement, is to illustrate the fact, learning a programming language is easy.  Being able to use it to program something from scratch requires actual skill.

Comment: I have another example.  Almost anyone can learn to play a musical instrument.  Fewer people are able to learn a song and perhaps play a small variation of that song (i.e. cover band).  However, it takes real musical talent, to create your own song from scratch.  There isn't a "how to become a programmer for dummies" book that exist.  You can learn a programming language but you cannot learn literally learn "how to program".  Some individuals it comes naturally (Bill Gates, Elon Musk, Mark Zuckerberg), other's struggle their entire career.

Comment: @Donald It is a bit like music.  There's also lots of different things that go into software development, and people aren't always masters at all of them (thankfully, that's not even required).  That said, the "naturally talented" programmer is mostly a myth.  People are recognized for their talent long after they put in the work to create the talent, and the "naturally" part of that equation is mostly people failing to recognizance the work they've invested.   That said, in programming, simplicity is beauty, so a simpler solution is typically "genius"

Comment: I do believe programming requires some degree of talent.  I had team members in college, on projects, that couldn't code a basic for loop but could study enough for an exam to pass it.  I do believe it takes talent to look at a section of code, have a compiler error, and know exactly what the problem is.  Since there are literally thousands of compiler errors, you can't learn them all, and some compiler errors are used for multiple reasons.  **Yes;  I am a programmer and I believe I am some degree of natural talent for the craft.** I might also be a natural leader, who can't stand, idle hands.

Comment: @Donald A programming exam that could be passed by a person who can't write a loop is an example of a "knowledge based exam" and not a "skill based exam".  Like I said before, the two are different items, and employers hire for skill.  Honestly, nobody was born knowing this stuff, so I don't believe in inherit talent when it comes to programming; but, I'll agree that some people do better at it than others.  We generally aren't in a position to know why.  I've been called talented by my peers, even gifted.  But, they don't see the time I put in to get here.  When I started, I sucked too.

Comment: Did you suck or did you simply not have the knowledge at the time?  A singer has to learn how to warm up their voice, by using vocal exercises, they do that by repetition.  Doesn't mean that singer can't have natural talent for that craft.  You might put in the hours to improve your craft for the next project, but so does a singer, when they are working on their next album.

Comment: @Donald I sucked (back then) because I was eight, and had not made the mistakes that I eventually learned from to become better.  That was over 40 years ago; but, then I was unaware of my own code's problems, focusing only on how to "make it work" without a care in the world about "how to make it clear, concise, and maintainable".  Having two relatives in the symphony and orchestra, I assure you that their talent was hard earned.  Natural talent is (often) a cop-out in the observer to not recognize the work done to obtain it.

Comment: As somebody who spent 12 years attempting to learn how to properly sing, I know that I don't have the talent for it, even if I had the drive to learn the craft.

Comment: @Donald In the upper levels, that might be so; but, singing can require body parts to enter the upper levels.  For example, no matter how much I practice Basketball, I'm just not tall enough to compete in the NBA.  Programming might require clear thinking, but there's not strong evidence that clear thinking / unclear thinking / thinking in general is directly impacted by specific breeding.  Most (if not all) of what's needed to program is learned, and then practiced.

Comment: @Donald and @ Edwin - Thank You for You deep insight. I’m in the middle of CS50 programming course. There is knowledge and practice (labs, problem-sets). I believe that skill is earned by learning and practicing the knowledge. Could You recommend a book on programming for a beginner like me? I will much appreciate.

Comment: @RafalH123 - One doesn’t learn programming from a book

Comment: @Donald - If not book then maybe a programing course?

Comment: @Donald Honestly, many courses at many locations aren't always great.  Sometimes they really are good, but bad teaching can be found everywhere.  The worst courses literally read the book to you in class sessions, so it's a fair statement to say "try saving your money, if you can learn from books.  Buy a book and read it".  The "Dietel and Dietel" books are pretty good at teaching a new person how to program along with teaching them the language (two different things).  Other books appeal to other people.  It all depends

Comment: @RafalH123 If you know how to program already, avoid the "learn to program while learning a language" books, and go straight to the books that teach "language only" or "toolkit only"  A quick google search will often the best books for your topic.  Read a few reviews, and select a "hit book", which are typically expensive.  For those knowing how to program, and looking to make their programming better, go with the "refactoring / design patterns / refactoring to design patterns / unit testing / software development type books"  They apply to all languages, even if written with one in mind.